# Filtered Group-How to group one column with and add calculated columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

DATASET I CURRENTLY HAVE-

```
COUNTRY city    id  tag dummy
India   ackno   1   2   1
China   open    0   0   1
India   ackno   1   2   1
China   open    0   0   1
USA     open    0   0   1
USA     open    0   0   1
China   ackno   1   2   1
USA     ackno   1   2   1
USA     resol   1   0   1
Russia  open    0   0   1
Italy   open    0   0   1
```

```py
country=df['country'].unique().tolist()
city=['resol','ackno']


#below are the preferred filters for calculating column percentage
df_looped=df[(df['city'].isin(city)) & (df['id']!=0) | (df['tag']!=0)]
percentage=(df_looped/df)*100

df_summed=df.groupby(['COUNTRY']).agg({'COUNTRY':'count'})
summed=df_summed['COUNTRY'].sum(axis=0)
```

THE DATASET I WANT-

```
COUNTRY percentage  summed
india   100%          2
China   66.66%        3
USA     25%           4
Russia  0%            1
Italy   0%            1
```

percentage should be derived from the above formula for every unique country and same for the sum.
percentage variable and summed variable should populate the columns.

Comment: might be worth making the logic explicit rather that having us trying to guess ;)

Comment: What is unclear?

Comment: "*with filters*" -> which ones? "*calculated*" -> what kind? Also, what is wrong with your current code? If it is wrong, should we really use it as source to try to understand what you want?

Comment: Hope this makes it easier

Comment: why is `66%` if there are 1 match values from 3? How is count it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create helper column `a` by your conditions and for percentages of `True`s use `mean`, for count values used [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) (because [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) omit misisng values and here no missing values) and last divide columns:

```
city=['resol','ackno']

df = (df.assign(a = (df['city'].isin(city) & (df['id']!=0) | (df['tag']!=0)))
        .groupby('COUNTRY', sort=False)
        .agg(percentage= ('a','mean'),summed=('a', 'size'))
        .assign(percentage = lambda x: x['percentage'].mul(100).round(2))
        )
print (df)
         percentage  summed
COUNTRY                    
India        100.00       2
China         33.33       3
USA           50.00       4
Russia         0.00       1
Italy          0.00       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_table` with a dict of functions to apply to your dataframe. You have to assign before a new column with your conditions (`looped`):

```
funcs = {
    'looped': [
        ('percentage', lambda x: f"{round(sum(x) / len(x) * 100, 2)}%"),
        ('summed', 'size')
  ]
}

# Your code without df[...]
looped = (df['city'].isin(city)) & (df['id'] != 0) | (df['tag'] != 0)

out = df.assign(looped=looped).pivot_table('looped', 'COUNTRY', aggfunc=funcs)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
        percentage  summed
COUNTRY                   
China       33.33%       3
India       100.0%       2
Italy         0.0%       1
Russia        0.0%       1
USA          50.0%       4
```